# CLIPS and integration with C++

Tags: c++, rule-engine, clips

I am in the process of developing a fairly complex rules engine. So I decided to take help of any GNU rules engine and get it integrated with my application. I came across [CLIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS) as a good rules engine.

Now, My application is in C++ and I want a sample way (a Hello world kind of program) from which I can learn how to integrate the .clp rules engine to my C++ application.

**Question**

1. My application is developed on Linux/AIX/HP and Mingw (for windows). Can we develop rules engine in CLIPS and get it integrated to C++ application on all these platforms? Can you please share a link on how to integrate.
2. The fundamental reason for going into an rules engine is that, I have experienced that rules "built" within my C/C++ application takes huge memory/CPU. I am under the impression that by using a rules engine, I can achieve the same in a more optimized (better resource utilization) way. Can CLIPS help me achieve that?

---

**Update 1:**

- What kind of application are you developing?
  To put it in a line,I am developing a filter match based counter. User may increment (NetworkID=XYZ, Increment count = 7), (NetworkID = MNO, Increment count=934)... etc. Now you get a query for NetworkID=X*, then I need to provide all count from XAA...XZZ. It is updated in multiple process, multiple thread across different node (distributed environment).
- Why do you have expert system rules inside, and what kind of rules?
  Now, My platform/application is in C++ (where user does increment/decrement/query). Now I want to use a rules engine to aid me in these. Writing the logic in C/C++ code seems to kill more resource that needed.

PS: The critical code related to increment/decrement/query are all in optimized c code. Some wrappers are in C++ code. So I am checking for rules engine to do it for me which can be invoked from my platform/application (in C/C++ code).

Comment: What kind of application are you developping, why do you have expert system rules inside, and what kind of rules?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Updated the question to answer your points.

Comment: It seems that CLIPS is mostly Java today. Did you consider embedding a high-level scripting interpreter inside your application?

Comment: CLIPS does exist for C, but it might be not maintained a lot. Use `clisp` and `libclips-dev`  packages on Debian or Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to integrate CLIPS with C++ is to use the compiler option (if available) to compile the C code as C++ code. From Section 1.2, C++ Compatibility, of the Advanced Programming Guide (http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v624/apg.htm):

> The CLIPS source code can now be compiled using either an ANSI C or
>   C++ compiler. Minimally, non-ANSI C compilers must support full ANSI
>   style function prototypes and the void data type in order to compile
>   CLIPS. If you want to make CLIPS API calls from a C++ program, it is
>   usually easier to do the integration by compiling the CLIPS source
>   files as C++ files. This removes the need to make an extern "C"
>   declaration in your C++ program for the CLIPS APIs. Some programming
>   environments allow you to specify the whether a file should be
>   compiled as C or C++ code based on the file extension. Other
>   environments allow you to explicitly specify which compiler to use
>   regardless of the extension (e.g. in gcc the option “-x c++” will
>   compile .c files as C++ files). In some environments, the same
>   compiler is used to compile both C and C++ programs and the compiler
>   uses the file extension to determine whether the file should be
>   compiled as a C or C++ program. In this situation, changing the .c
>   extension of the CLIPS source files to .cpp usually allows the source
>   to be compiled as a C++ program.

Optionally you can try using something like clipsmm (http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsmm/) which is a C++ interface to the CLIPS library.